# How to add class in <a> tag using Textile Markup language

Tags: textile

I am using Textile Markup language. I am stucked at one thing:-

```
"Do (D above middle C)":https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/Do+bell.mp3
```

above code shows  HTML `<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/Do+bell.mp3" title="D above middle C">Do</a>`

in this  tag how can I add a class named "fancybox" so it will show `'<a>'` tag with this class.

Please Help.!!

Comment: are you looking for this ??

<a href="" class="className">

Comment: thanks for reply @ annam priyatam. yes I want exactly what you said.But I have found my solution on this link "http://txstyle.org/doc/12/links".

Comment: okk good luck.. Have a Nice Day...

Answer (score 0):

```
"(class-name)Do (D above middle C)":https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/Do+bell.mp3
```